# Error in using multi-dimensional array with spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner, multidimensional-array

I am getting  error for the following code which implements `Spinner` with multi-dimensional array.

```
Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);        
String dept[][] ={{"cs","101"},{"me","102"}};           
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dept);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    
sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What error you are getting and on which line ? Post your logcat along with the detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm getting this error...    the constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(Second,int,String[][]) is undefined    ....getting this in program..

Comment: And what error you are getting on that line? Post the logcat.

Comment: I have not executed the program bcz I'am getting the error in program only...Actually my question is - can we use multi-dimensional array to implement spinner? If yes, please provide me an sample example for implementing that...